# local storage using html5

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

I need to store the values that the user enters in each of the boxes through html5. When the user refreshes the page, it should keep the values in each of the text boxes. I had a friend tell me that this would work, but it's not and I'm not getting any errors in the console.

```
<script>
function storageValue() {
    var uno = document.getElementById("storage1");
    var duck = uno.value
    var dos = document.getElementById("storage2");
    var duckie = dos.value
    var tres = document.getElementById("storage3");
    var rubberDuck = tres.value
    var quatro = document.getElementById("storage4");
    var rubberDuckie = quatro.value
    alert("Your stored values are: " + duck + "," + duckie + "," + rubberDuck + "," + rubberDuckie);
    localStorage.setItem('duck', duck);
    localStorage.setItem('duckie', duckie);
    localStorage.setItem('rubberDuck', rubberDuck);
    localStorage.setItem('rubberDuckie', rubberDuckie);
    checkLocalStorage();
}

function checkLocalStorage() {
    var poodle = document.getElementById('storage1').value
    poodle.innerHTML = localStorage["duck"] 
    var cow = document.getElementById('storage2').value
    poodle.innerHTML = localStorage["duckie"]
    var dog = document.getElementById('storage3').value
    dog.innerHTML = localStorage["rubberDuck"]
    var cat = document.getElementById('storage4').value
    cat.innerHTML = localStorage["rubberDuckie"];
}

checkLocalStorage();
```

Here's the HTML that I have:

```
<body align="center" style="background-color:red;">
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Local Storage</h1>
        </header>
        <input type="text" id="storage1" size="40" placeholder="Please enter a value">
        <input type="text" id="storage2" size="40" placeholder="Please enter a value">
        <input type="text" id="storage3" size="40" placeholder="Please enter a value">
        <input type="text" id="storage4" size="40" placeholder="Please enter a value">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="addValue" value="Store Input Values" onclick='storageValue();'>
        <div id="storageDiv"></div>
        <nav>
            <p>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </nav>

        <div>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy; Copyright  by Alan Sylvestre
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is `storageValue()` being called? Have you stepped through with the debugger? Does the alert appear?

Comment: The error is that it doesn't store the value in the text box when you refresh the page. The form resets itself.

Comment: Oh wait, it works just fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Is there something that would be making that difference?

Answer (score 2):

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9BN5r/

The problem is you are trying to set the innerHTML of an input field.  You need to set the value. Change your `checkLocalStorage()` function to:

```
function checkLocalStorage() {
    var poodle = document.getElementById('storage1');
    poodle.value = localStorage['duck'];

    var cow = document.getElementById('storage2');
    cow.value = localStorage['duckie'];

    var dog = document.getElementById('storage3');
    dog.value = localStorage['rubberDuck'];

    var cat = document.getElementById('storage4');
    cat.value = localStorage['rubberDuckie'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below was taken from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  // Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support!
  // Some code.....
  }
else
  {
  // Sorry! No web storage support..
  }
```

Your friend is right, localStorage should work with [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp). Are you sure that your website is working correctly with HTML5 ()

> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

Without more information about the errors, this is all I can really recommend.

EDIT: From the comment, it's not working in Chrome - are you sure Chrome has been updated recently?

Comment: I'm not sure it has been updated. I wil check that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `storageValue` function seems okay, but your `checkLocalStorage` function needs fixing;

You'll need something a bit more symmetrical:

```
localStorage.setItem('duck', document.getElementById("storage1").value);
...
document.getElementById("storage1").value = localStorage.getItem('duck');
```

preferably with some code for providing default values and value checking, etc..

but what you have in your `checkLocalStorage` function is:

```
var poodle = document.getElementById('storage1').value
poodle.innerHTML = localStorage["duck"]
```

... which doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // working
    } else {
        // Not Support
    }
    Store Data

    //Syntax 
    localStorage.setItem(Key,Value);
    //By localStorage Object  Method

    localStorage.setItem('name','TEST');

    Retrieve Data
    var a = localStorage.getItem('name');
    alert(a); //Output : TEST


    Remove Data
    localStorage.removeItem('name');


    Remove All Data
    localStorage.clear();
```

[Test Demo](http://qaify.com/blog/web-storage-in-html5-with-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-example/)

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and add a description (you should make "Retrieve Data" and your other comments actual comments).